# Is it kosher to have document.ready and window.load in the same JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it okay to have both wrapper functions in the same JavaScript file? For example, the main.js file which contains all of my site's scripts currently is using the `$(window).load(function(){//...});` method and I was wondering if I could also utilize the `$(document).ready(function(){//...});` method in the same script file?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Code here...
});

$(window).load(function() {
    // Code here...
});
```

Comment: You can use multiple $(document).ready blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do different things, so yes.

- `$(document).ready()` fires when the DOM is ready to be modified.
- `$(window).load()` fires when all of the external resources like images, scripts and stylesheets have finished loading.

Even if they were both the same (e.g. both were `$(document.ready()`), jQuery would still execute both of the bound callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is nothing wrong with this.  In fact, those two events are for completely different things.

Since you are using jQuery to handle these events, you can even have multiple handlers.